# SuiteCRM REST API v8 Not working with Nginx (ubuntu 18.0)

Tags: nginx, suitecrm

I try to get access token Using REST API v8 but getting 404 . error.

I have change nginx conf file for rewrire rules but it's not working .

```
 location /api {
  rewrite ^/api/(.*?)$ /lib/API/public/index.php/$1 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue with SuiteCRM 7.11.5 configured in Ngnix. Access token cant be available on calling the API. There is some sort of redirections issues faced in suitecrm with nginx. It is to better to update your docker. server with Apache and predefined .htaccess file in directories.

This fixed our issue on 404 error in API response.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
location ~ /Api/ {
    index   index.php;
    try_files $uri @rewrite_api;

    location ~ \.php {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}

location @rewrite_api {
    rewrite ^/Api/(.*)?$    /Api/index.php/$1       last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the response to make it work with access token request `Api/access_token`
It has to look like

```
location @rewrite_api {
    rewrite ^/Api/access_token(.*)?$    /Api/index.php/$1       last;
    rewrite ^/Api/(.*)?$    /Api/index.php/$1       last;
}
```